# Why is it saying stack is empty even though I push something into it?

Tags: java

For some reason when I call the stack1.empty() or stack1.isEmpty(), it returns true even though I pushed something into the stack? Here is the method I use to push something into the stack...

```
//Case B:
     else if(currentChar == '('){
         Character charObj = Character.valueOf('(');
         stack1.push(charObj);
         System.out.println("Case B");
     }
```

Basically it iterates through each character in a string, and does one of the cases that I coded. In this case, the character is a '(', so I have it pushed into the stack.

Now, the next character in the string is a letter, so this case is called:

```
//Case A:
     if(currentChar != '+' && currentChar != '-' && currentChar != '*' && currentChar != '/' && currentChar != '(' && currentChar != ')' ){
         postfixString += currentChar;
         System.out.println("Case A");
     }
```

That method works fine. Now the next part goes wrong for some reason. The next thing in the string is a *. SO, it's supposed to run a certain case that I coded, but instead it runs a different case....Here is the case that it runs:

```
//Case C:
     else if(stack1.empty() && currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/'){
         stack1.push(currentChar);
         System.out.println("Case C");
     }
```

As you can see, the only way to run this case is if the stack *is* empty, but it's not empty! I pushed something into the stack... I don't understand why it keeps running this case even though the stack is not empty.

I want it to run this case instead:

```
     //Case D: If character is an operator, it goes into a loop checking if topstack is higher precedence to the current character
     // If it is, the stack pops onto the end of the postfix string. If it isn't, the stack pushes the current scanned character.
     // It then breaks out of the loop
     else if(currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/' && !stack1.isEmpty()){
         char topStack = stack1.peek();

        while(!stack1.isEmpty()){
            if(precedence(topStack, currentChar)){
                postfixString += stack1.pop();
            }
            else{
                stack1.push(currentChar);
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Case D");

        }



     }
```

I mean it should run case D, but instead it runs case C. Why is it doing this?

EDIT:

Here's the entire class:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixToPostfixConverter
{
//**********************************************************************
//The precedence method determines the precedence between two operators.
//If the first operator is of higher or equal precedence than the second
//operator, it returns the value true, otherwise it returns false.
//***********************************************************************
   public static boolean precedence(char topStack, char currentChar)
   {
   if(topStack == currentChar){
       return true;
   }

   // If topStack is division or multiplication, it will always have precedence no matter what
   if(topStack == '/' || topStack == '*'){
       return true;
   }
   // If topStack is addition or subtraction...
   else if(topStack == '+' || topStack == '-'){
       if(currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-'){
           return true;
       }
       else if(currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/'){
           return false;
       }
   }

   return false;
   }

//*************************************************************************
//The static convertToPostfix method will convert the infixString
//into the corresponding postfix string. Check the algorithm on
//assignment #11's description page. Mark each case clearly inside the code
//*************************************************************************
   public static String convertToPostfix(String infixString)
   {
  //initialize the resulting postfix string
  String postfixString = "";

  //initialize the stack
  Stack<Character> stack1 = new Stack<Character>();

 //Obtain the character at index i in the string
  for (int i=0; i < infixString.length(); i++)
  {
     char currentChar = infixString.charAt(i);

    //Case A:
     if(currentChar != '+' && currentChar != '-' && currentChar != '*' && currentChar != '/' && currentChar != '(' && currentChar != ')' ){
         postfixString += currentChar;
         System.out.println("Case A");
     }

    //Case B:
     else if(currentChar == '('){
         stack1.push(currentChar);
         System.out.println("Case B");
     }

     else if(currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/'){
         //Case C
         if(stack1.isEmpty()){
             stack1.push(currentChar);
             System.out.println("Case C");
         }
         //Case D
         else{
             char topStack = stack1.peek();

             while(!stack1.isEmpty()){
                if(precedence(topStack, currentChar)){
                    postfixString += stack1.pop();
                }
                else{
                    stack1.push(currentChar);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Case D");

            }
         }
     }
    //Case E:
     else if(currentChar == ')' && !stack1.isEmpty()){
         while(!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek() != '('){
             postfixString += stack1.pop();
             System.out.println("Case E");
         }
         if(!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek() == '('){
             stack1.pop();
         }
     }


  } //end of for loop


    //Case F:
  if(!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek() == '('){
      return "No matching close parenthesis error.";
  }
  else if(!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek() != '('){
      while(!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek() != '('){
          postfixString += stack1.pop();
      }
  }

  System.out.println("Case F");
  return postfixString;


}//end of convertToPostfix method

}//end of the InfixToPostfixConverter class
```

Comment: Add some parentheses in the right places for Case C and D

Comment: What do you mean? @A--C

Answer (score 4):

The `&&` operator has a higher precedence than `||`, so in this statement:

```
else if(stack1.empty() && currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/'){
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
else if( ( stack1.empty() && currentChar == '+' ) || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/'){
```

For a simpler example:

```
if (a && b || c)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( (a && b) || c )
```

When in doubt, add parens to make the order of operations explicit so that you (and other programmers reading your code) are clear on your intention.

### Explanation

What this means for your overall question is, your `stack1` is probably **not** empty. In the `else if` I've quoted above, `stack1.empty() && currentChar == '+'` would both have to be true. Since that isn't the case, the next terms are evaluated until it gets to `currentChar == '*'`, which **is** true, so it runs Case C.

Your Case D will never be true, because Case C already checks the same characters. Case D will not be reached.

Assuming Case C is supposed to mean both "stack1 is empty" AND "currentChar is one of +, -, *, or /", then you would need to write it as such:

```
else if (stack1.empty() && (currentChar == '+' || ...)) {
```

But since you are checking for the same characters every time, I would personally use a multi-level `if` statement:

```
else if (currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || ...) {
    if (stack1.empty()) {
    // Case C

    } else {
    // Case D

    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to   else if((stack1.empty()) && (currentChar == '+' || currentChar == '-' || currentChar == '*' || currentChar == '/')){

Comment: Now instead of going to case D, it goes to case B?

Comment: I don't understand. Now instead of going to case D since it's *, it goes to case B?

Comment: Your change (from your first comment) looks like it should solve the immediate problem. I don't see how changing a later chained conditional could cause an earlier one to trigger instead. However, you posted your code in pieces, so I guess it's possible that Case B comes after Case D in your code? I updated my answer with a more detailed example; if that doesn't help, perhaps you could post your example code all in one block (not in separate pieces), so I can see exactly what is going on?

Comment: Case B is before case D. I will post all of the code. Also thank you for your response. I learned something new.

Comment: Thanks for posting the complete class. Much easier to review! According to that code, I can see no way for it to go to Case B if `currentChar == '*'`. How do you know `currentChar` was `*` **at that exact time?** You already have some debug `println` statements; that's great. I'd suggest taking those a step further with something like `System.out.println("Case B. currentChar = " + currentChar);`. Printing the actual value of the variable(s) you are tracking is often very helpful when you get surprising results.

Comment: Ok, I added that to debug. For the input I put in (a+b)*c. For some reason it read (, then 'a', but then it totally skipped the '+' sign and went straight to 'b'.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out a pattern. Whenever an operator is inside parenthesis, it skips over it. Whenever it's outside parenthesis, it runs it fine. Not sure what is causing this...

Comment: My advice in this case is, just keep going using the same debugging method: Put those debug statements at the **top** of **every** case so you are guaranteed to see `Case ?, currentChar = ?` for _every_ character, until you are confident your logic is correct. Another minor note, I would suggest moving the Case D `println` statement to the very top of the case (you have it after the `while` loop).

Comment: To me at least it seems my logic is correct. I'm not sure why it's only skipping the operator characters after a parenthesis is called.

Comment: If it "skips" operators in parentheses, that means your Case C and Case D logic is coming into play. Within parentheses, `stack1` is not empty. Outside of parenthesis, `stack1` is empty. As mentioned, judicious use of debugging statements will help you figure out what is going on. At this point, I believe we've solved your posted question, right? I'd be happy to help you a little more with further debugging, but if so, let's move further discussion to chat, since we're moving beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Ok, I just kept running it over and over and somehow it's working now. Maybe I didn't save it before running the code?

Comment: Yeah something is wrong with my case D, and I can't figure it out